# SSL Certificate: http vs https

Tags: ssl-certificate

I'm about to get an SSL Certificate for my website.  In particular, it will be used because I'm switching over to a payment processor which requires it.  A few "noob" questions:

1) Will I have to change any code that directs users to http://www.mysite.com to https://www.mysite.com, or will users who go to http://www.mysite.com be automatically re-directed to https://www.mysite.com?

2) I assume that https "slows" things down on a site?  If this is the case, can I maintain the http everywhere on my site except when they make a payment to the processor?  i.e. http://www.mysite.com/any_old_page.php, while https://www.mysite.com/pay_for_the_stuff.php

Thanks!

Comment: Don't assume. *Benchmark*.

Comment: No, getting a certificate doesn't automatically redirect URLs. Many sites only use SSL for certain pages (e.g. just the login form), not everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, that won't happen automatically. You will have to change your server configuration to do that.
2. Yes, it slows things down. How much depends on the cipher suite used for the server, the server software and hardware. You should play around with different TLS cipher suites to see how much. It depends on that (and of the nature of your site) if you should only use TLS on part of your site or all of your site. As for the requirements of the payment processor: ASK!